# What are the requirements for using chrome.experimental.webRequest?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrequest

I am playing with the Chrome Experimental API and having a little hard time making it work. Do I need to have the devtools open for the chrome.experimental.webRequest to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you need to enable experimental API on `chrome://flags` page and declare `experimental` permission in your manifest. It's all described [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/experimental.html).